# Start Emacs in VHDL-mode?

Tags: customize, customization

I started coding in vhdl and I'm currently using emacs with its vhdl mode as editor on Ubuntu 16.04 OS. 
However i was wondering if its possible to start emacs already in vhdl mode, meaning I won't have to enable the vhdl mode every time after starting emacs (m-x vhdl-mode).

Comment: Do you want your scratch buffer to start in `vhdl-mode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs as a whole doesn't have a "vhdl-mode", because you can use several buffers at the same times in the same Emacs session, with some buffers using vhdl-mode while others use verilog-mode.

The mode used for a file is usually decided based on the file name, using `auto-mode-alist`.  So what you want to do is to make sure your files have names that are recognized as "files using vhdl-mode" by `auto-mode-alist`.

If your file names have the shape `<foo>.vhdl` or `<foo>.vhd` then Emacs should automatically use `vhdl-mode` for them.  If your file names look different (e.g. they have the shape `<foo>.myext`), then explain it to Emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.myext\\'" . vhdl-mode))
```